# Does twitter support webhooks for chatbots or should i use Stream API?

Tags: python, api, twitter, twitter-oauth, chatbot

I am trying to build a twitter chat bot which is interactive and replies according to incoming messages from users. Webhook documentation is unclear on how do I receive incoming message notifications. I'm using python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.
Webhook isn't needed, after searching for long hours on Twitter Documentation, I made a well working DM bot, it uses Twitter Stream API, and StreamListener class from tweepy, whenever a DM is received, I send requests to REST API which sends DM to the mentioned recipient.

Comment: Good to hear - the user streams API that delivers Direct Messages will be retired after the Account Activity API comes out of beta, so be aware that you will need to rework your code to support webhooks in the future. The beta Direct Messages features are able to support quick replies etc as you have already found.

Answer (score 0):

The new Webhooks format (Account Activity API) is currently only available for Direct Messages. If you have applied for, and been granted, access you can register your webhook receiver and the API will send you incoming direct messages. This API is currently in beta. There's a [sample in node](https://github.com/twitterdev/twitter-webhook-boilerplate-node) on Twitter's developer Github sample repo.

Comment: Hey Andy, I am trying to contact you, I figured out a way by using Tweepy stream feature, but I'm unable to send buttons/quick replies/media through it. Any fix?

Comment: The streaming API is only for receiving Tweets. You need to use the Direct Message posting API. The documentation is here -> https://dev.twitter.com/rest/direct-messages

Comment: I found  fix to it, i am using stream api to trigger functions which send request to rest API, whenever a DM is received thanks anyway